# Dot product result has wrong dimension

Tags: matrix, products, dot

I'm doing a small project and I've encountered a problem while using Mathematica. I should mention that I'm kinda new to this software, so maybe it's just something I haven't grasped yet.

Anyway, I have a *9x9 matrix* `P` and a *9D vector* `q0Dot`.

Evaluating

```
projected = P.q0Dot
```

ended up taking a very long computational time. My laptop is quite powerful, but after I waited for like 10-15 minutes, I aborted the evaluation. I was kinda expecting slow evaluation, since the computational time of products is not linear.

So I reverted to calculate one element at a time, like:

```
a = P[[1, All]] . q0Dot
```

and so on (just one is enough for the sake of this post).

Now, the problem I've encountered is that `a` (and other elements of the result vector)  <del>is not a 9D vector, as it should be.</del>  is not a scalar.

I don't think it's related to the fact that Mathematica doesn't treat lists as row or column vectors. Correct me if I'm wrong.

To show what happened:

```
Dimensions[P]
Dimensions[q0Dot]
Dimensions[a]
```

> ```
> {9, 9}
> {9}
> {8}
> ```

Note that almost every element of `P` cointains sine and cosine expressions and is fairly complicated.

So I was wondering what the problem is and made a couple of theories, but have found out nothing so far.

- maybe one element (maybe the last one) was null, so it got ignored at the end, but that's not the case;
- maybe the computational time is exceeding the maximum allowed and it stops computing without a warning, but I don't really know how to check that;
- maybe there's some Mathematica behaviour I don't know about

I'd be really really grateful if any of you could point me out at the solution!

**EDIT:**
I'm adding my code, which I didn't do at first because I thought it would have been too detailed for the post itself. Also, it's making use of an external library, which I'm adding too.

 [My code + library - Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1KjDUtK4m9qmZ--cWOp_f3YbdpV1Fe3Fe)

Now: it's an Inverse Kinematics problem, dealing with an industrial robotic arm.
The matrix `P` (along with the others) contains only sines and cosines, but quite an amount, since it has 9 variables.

> Unless you're doing something considerably more complicated than just
>   having a dot product of integers or Reals, It should be super fast to
>   calculate

In fact, I've tried that and didn't encounter any problems, as **morbo** stated.

Now I'm a bit confused. `P . q0Dot` should be a 9D vector, since it's a 9x9 matrix multiplied by a 9D (column) vector. As all of you stated, multiplying one row of `P`, which is a 9D (row) vector, by `q0Dot` should result in a scalar. 
<sub>*Well, blame my stupidty for this one, since I made a gaffe (which I'm going to highlight): maybe I didn't focus enough, since this should be obvious, duh.*</sub> 
 So why isn't it? Now I'm concerned about two things: one, is why that doesn't result in a scalar; two, what kind of computation Mathematica did to achieve that 8D result. Which may be the same problem in my case.

I think this is everything you asked for, to improve my question. If not, I'll surely add some more!

Comment: If you can show the actual matrices, we could help better. A dot product ought to execute extremely fast for a 9 x 9 problem.

Comment: Also, you are right that Mathematica's handling of "vectors" is quirky. In my own work, I write my vectors as (for example) 9 x 1 matrices in order to ensure Mathematica is doing the exact matrix function I want.

Comment: With the dimensions you show, p[[1, All]].q should be a scalar, not a 9D vector. p[[1,All]] is the first row of p. Taking the dot product of a 9D row and the 9D q gives a scalar quantity.

Comment: As a test, try: `Do[Print[n, " ", 
  Timing[projected = 
     Take[P, {1, n}, {1, n}].Take[q0Dot, n]][[1]]], {n, 9}]` to see the increase in timing and where it gets bogged down.

Comment: The first mistake in your notebook is that you use sin[theta] instead of Sin[theta]. Symbols in Mathematica are case sensitive.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [184653](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/184653/45431)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fix

Although I agree with  @MichaelE2 that inverting a symbolic matrix is asking for trouble!

First, in your `W` matrix, write `1/2` instead of `0.5` and some odd numerical behaviors downstream are averted. When it is time to simplify things, the algorithms can do a little better.

Second, it doesn't hurt to keep simplifying your code as you go, so for example using `FullSimplify` early and simplifying `JRNonInv` helps keep the bloat down when you invert the matrix.

```
JTransposed = Transpose[J];
JSimplified = J // FullSimplify;  (* was just a simplify here *)
JTSimplified = Transpose@JSimplified ;   (* no need to simplify JTransposed *)  

JRNonInv = (JSimplified.WInverse.JTSimplified) // Simplify; (* added a simplify *)
```

To your point on the code not working, if you replace `q0Dot` with a "proper" vector...

```
qvec = Transpose@{q0Dot};
qvec // Dimensions
```

> {9,1}

Your code now works, at least in creating the correct sized matrices.

```
Dimensions[P]
Dimensions[qvec]
Dimensions[a]
```

> {9, 9}
>
> {9, 1}
>
> {1}

You can also skip the intermediate variables and go

```
 projected = P.qvec
 Dimensions@projected
```

> {9,1}

I firmly believe how Mathematica allows you to define a vector as a simple list when dealing with linear algebra is the Devil's work, and has caused many a heartbreak for me.

**EDIT**

@ slim71, here's an example of what I mean. Define a simple "vector"

```
vsimp = {1,1,1};
vsimp//TeXForm
```

$$
\{1,1,1\}
$$

If you just do `MatrixForm` it looks like a vector, but it's not really one. Now make a full-blown column vector, which is a $3 \times 1$ matrix.

```
vector = Transpose@{{1, 1, 1}};
vector//TeXForm
```

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 1 \\
 1 \\
 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Create a simple matrix to play with

```
mat = Table[i,{i,3},{3}];
mat//TeXForm
```

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 2 & 2 & 2 \\
 3 & 3 & 3 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Now in theory we can do `mat.vector` but not `vector.mat` since the dimensions would be incompatible in the second case.

```
mat.vector
```

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 3 \\
 6 \\
 9 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

The command `vector.mat` fails, complaining about incompatible shapes. Give it a try.

In the other case, we *can* execute both `vsimp.mat` and `mat.vsimp`, depending on Mathematica to interpret `vsimp` either as a row vector or column vector given the context. You can easily get burned with a mistake here. Writing the vector as a matrix helps to prevent these mistakes, and it appears to fix the error in your code, which ought to work correctly. Not sure why it doesn't, other than that you've got a monstrous term for the inverse of the matrix.

Finally, you can't just do `Transpose@vsimp` since you transpose matrices, and `vsimp` is just a list.

```
Transpose@vsimple
(* Transpose::nmtx: The first two levels of {1,1,1} cannot be transposed. *)
```

Instead you are constructing a matrix to represent your column vector.

Comment: I haven't seen the format `Transpose@{q0Dot}` before, is it the same of `q0Dot // Transpose`? If not, could you please point out some reference? I've tried searching it but I don't know if that use has a "name" itself, so to speak..
<br>
I agree with simplifying the code as I go: I guess `FullSimplify` is better than `Simplify` in the end, so I might as well use that. What I didn't know was this behaviour with `1/2` instead of `0.5` and similar! Thanks for the suggestion!
<br>
Finally, I don't quite like Mathematica vector usage myself, since I'm used to other languages.. Gonna try!

Comment: OK, tried and it works as expected for now!
I had to avoid some `FullSimplify`s and `Simplify`s because the computations were going on for too long (it even reported "Computational time exceeded" or something like that, I don't remember the actual text), but so far this is the solution I've searched for!

Comment: too many comments maybe, sorry about that...
But @MikeY
A suggestion: should I do the `Transpose` of a list every time I want to use it as a column vector like in this occasion?

Answer (score 1):

It'd be great if you posted/would show your code and matrices to see exactly what you're doing. It's a good habit to post your attempt (and your data) for us to play with.

Unless you're doing something considerably more complicated than just having a dot product of integers or Reals, It should be super fast to calculate,

```
matA = Table[RandomReal[], {i, 1, 9}, {j, 1, 9}];
vectorB = Table[RandomReal[], {i, 1, 9}];
vectorC = MatrixForm[Dot[matA, vectorB]]
```

It took me 0.000014 to calculate...even a 20k x 20k matrix took less than a second.

Your second bit of code is giving you a scalar because you are doing a scalar product of the first column of your 9x9 matrix with a 9 element vector, thus giving you a scalar product.

With Table you can populate the scalar products into the solution:

```
test = Table[matA[[i, All]] . matB, {i, 1, 9}] // MatrixForm
```

This gives the same result, which can be verified so:

```
vectorC == test

(*True*)
```

So, I'm guessing you're code is a bit wonky. Please give your working (or none working code) and I will update accordingly.

**Addendum**

I just saw that you're also dealing with some trig functions, without knowing which they are, I made a completely symbolic example

```
params = {x -> RandomReal[], y -> RandomReal[], z -> RandomReal[]};
AbsoluteTiming[
 var = {Cos[x], Cos[x] + Sin[y], Tanh[z], ArcSin[x], E^z, 
   ArcSinh[x] Cos[y]};
 smatA = Table[var[[RandomInteger[{1, 6}]]], {i, 1, 9}, {j, 1, 9}];
 svectorB = Table[var[[RandomInteger[{1, 6}]]], {i, 1, 9}];
 svectorC = MatrixForm[Dot[smatA, svectorB]];
 test = Table[smatA[[i, All]].svectorB, {i, 1, 9}] // MatrixForm;]
svectorC == test /. params

(*{0.000805, Null}*)
(*True*)
```

This also took via AbsoluteTiming[] 0.000805 seconds to generate randomly all equations, params, and solve.

; If you didn't know is shorthand for no output.

Comment: The code in your addendum is incorrect. It never uses `smatA` and `svevtorB`, so the timing is suspect.

Comment: Ah! you're right, my apologies, it was a lazy copy and paste. I've added new codes. and then replaced all x y z values...to a total of still less than a second in time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm going to add my code, so bear a moment please..
I'll add some other consideration there, since I think are helpful
(I knew about the ;)

Comment: `MatrixForm` should not be used this way. It is a common source of problems for new users. See [this Q&A](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3098/why-does-matrixform-affect-calculations), para. 8 of [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395/4999) to the pitfall question, and [this reference](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node174.html).

Answer (score 1):

#### Edit

Since morbo has corrected his code, I no longer have any criticism of it to make, and simply offer this as alternative way of coding which is more concise and a little faster.

```
AbsoluteTiming[
  exprs = {Cos[x], Cos[x] + Sin[y], Tanh[z], ArcSin[x], E^z, ArcSinh[x] Cos[y]}; 
  matA = RandomChoice[exprs, {9, 9}];
  vecB = RandomChoice[exprs, 9];
  dot1 = matA.vecB;
  dot2 = Table[matA[[i]].vecB, {i, 9}];
  dot1 == dot2]
```

> `{0.000688, True}`

Comment: Well, one could have waited for me to wake up and correct my code, but there's no reason to attack my quality and style versus your own, or was there a point that I could learn besides you could gain 0.00005 seconds?

Comment: @morbo. I did not mean to criticize your style, but only of your errors. Since you have corrected your code, I have edited this answer and removed the criticism.

Comment: @morbo, m_goldberg: While I appreciate helpful attitude motivating your answers, my criticism would be that neither actually post answers the question. Your special case does not reproduce the problem of the OP's special case. The OP seems to know already how it should work, and there is nothing wrong with the OP's syntax and usage. Now, I don't believe the OP has accurately presented the case, esp. the `Dimensions[]` output given the descriptions of the variables. The OP needs to present the full code for this question to be answered.

Answer (score 1):

Note:

```
Head[P[[1]].q0Dot]
(*  Plus  *)
```

And:

```
ecnt = 0;
Replace[P[[1]].q0Dot, e_ :> ToString[Head[e]][++ecnt], 1]
(*
"Times"[1] + "Times"[2] + "Times"[3] + "Times"[4] + "Times"[5] + 
 "Times"[6] + "Times"[7] + "Times"[8]
*)
```

What's going on is that `Dimensions[]` is returning the dimensions of the expression with the head `Plus`, which expression consists of 8 terms being added.  `Dimensions` works with any head, not just `List`.

```
ArrayQ[P]
ArrayQ[q0Dot]
ArrayQ[a]
(*
  True
  True
  False
*)
```

Finally consider:

```
ByteCount[P] // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {10.5235, 19394763312}  *)
```

That's 19GB, which is more than my system can handle effectively. It also takes 10.5 sec for a simple operation. Currently, many of the subexpressions appear to be shared (since the `MemoryInUse` is a couple hundred MB). Almost any operation that causes `P` to be traversed (such as `Dot`) would take a long time, and if subexpressions need copying, it would require swapping. The kernel might even run out of memory and crash.

Maybe if you have 64+GB of RAM, things will work better.  Otherwise, see if you can deal more effectively with `P`.  One culprit is taking the `Inverse[]` of a symbolic matrix.  It's unlikely that one would be able to analyze such large symbolic expressions, so if you're ultimately going to do things numerically, then wait to construct `P` when all parameters are numeric. (Then you'll probably want to use `LinearSolve[]` instead of `Inverse[]`.)  It should be much, much faster.

Comment: So you're saying (if I understand it correctly) that `Dimensions` takes account of the actual format of the object, and this is the reason `a` results in a 8D object?
Also, unfortunately I kinda need the `Inverse[]` of the symbolic matrix `W`, otherwise I would have done it numerically as you suggested..

Comment: @slim71 I think you've got it right. `Dimensions[h[x,y,z]]` gives `{3}` and `Dimensions[h[h[1,2],h[3,4],h[5,6]]]` gives `{3, 2}` (provided `h` does not evaluate to something else). But it has to be a rectangular array with the same head `h`: Both `Dimensions[h[h[1, 2], h[3, 4], g[5, 6]]]` and `Dimensions[h[h[1, 2], h[3, 4], h[5, 6, 7]]]` yield `{3}` So in fact, your `a` is a scalar, which I should have emphasized in my